# Why is the change in reactive power not equal to the line reactance drop?

Tags: transmission-line, power-flow-analysis

I am working on an equivalent network of a two bus system right now.

[image]

I know the \$P\$, \$Q\$ and power factor at Bus 2. Bus 1 is taken as a slack bus (\$V = 1 PU\$, \$\delta\$ = 0). Using iterative techniques, the voltage and angle of Bus 2 was also found.

Subsequently, using these values, the current through the transmission line was found and the reactive power at Bus 1 was also calculated. Now, a change in reactive power at Bus 1 was introduced while still keeping the voltage at that bus constant.

The objective here was to bring a change in the Voltage at Bus 2.

As the voltage magnitude of Bus 2 changes, once again the current through the transmission line changes. This will lead to a change in the reactive power consumed by the reactance in the transmission line (hereafter referred to as "line reactance drop.")

I am expecting that the change in reactive power at Bus 1 should compensate the change in line reactance drop of the transmission line and change in reactive power delivered by the admittances. However this is not the case.

Why is this change in reactive power at the slack bus more than the change in line reactance drop?

Comment: _"This will lead to a change in the **reactive power consumed by the reactance** in the transmission line"_ - what do you mean by 'consumed'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott essentially that the $$I^2 * X$$ loss in the Tx line will change because the magnitude of Current through the line is going to change.

Comment: Reactance doesn't cause "loss". Nor does it "consume" power.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Electrical engineers speak of reactive power being produced and consumed. I don't remember whether it's capacitors or inductors that "produce" it, but the opposite one "consumes" it. It's just a way of talking about reactive power balance.

Comment: Probably inductors "consume" it, since most huge power grid loads are inductive, and that means the power grid operator has to add capacitors to "supply" it.